# Can I make Magento render HTML in shopping cart items?

Tags: cart, shopping-cart

We've got products with descriptions containing HTML.  Hovering over the Shopping Cart button they render just fine in the floating window.  However, upon clicking the cart button, the full screen shopping cart displays the HTML code instead of rendering it.  Is there a setting I need to change to get the full cart to render instead of displaying the HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick and dirty way around this would be to wrap where the description is output in a `html_entities_decode()` function.

The more involved way of dealing with this is to rewrite `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Output` with your own and then rework the `productAttribute()`method.

Comment: Upvote because it sounds useful.  No idea how to implement it right now, but will accept once I figure that out.  :-)